# rerun testng tests on configuration methods failure

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

I've found various methods to Rerun your failed TESTNG tests like by using `IRetryAnalyzer`,`ITestResult` , but if my configuration methods fail due to any reason like my `@BEFORECLASS` or `@BEFORETEST` or `@BEFOREMETHOD` how to rerun your test in such cases.